# Query XML in multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, dynamics-crm

I'm working with Dynamics Business Portal. In an attempt to join GP Dynamics EmployeeID with the user's AD Username, I've found a few tables that will help me with creating this hash. The only table I can find in the Business Portal tables that will tie the Business Portal to GP is called [MbfRoleUser]. Enough backstory, here's some sample data and how I'd like to have it displayed.

```
declare @table table(UserID varchar(50),Constituent varchar(200))
insert into @table values
('D8851830-EF23-44BE-BB17-0008D70F9F5B','<entityKey><Microsoft.Dynamics.Common.Company.Company ID="1" /><Microsoft.Dynamics.Hrm.Entity.Employee ID="002001" /></entityKey>')
,('78E42A10-D7CE-4B40-86F2-001549F5A3C2','<entityKey><Microsoft.Dynamics.Common.Company.Company ID="1" /><Microsoft.Dynamics.Hrm.Entity.Employee ID="001079" /></entityKey>')
,('1F899A87-6186-4E2B-BA18-0076A4D95836','<entityKey><Microsoft.Dynamics.Common.Company.Company ID="1" /><Microsoft.Dynamics.Hrm.Entity.Employee ID="001997" /></entityKey>')
,('CB043358-0B16-4055-A806-00A63964C1A9','<entityKey><Microsoft.Dynamics.Common.Company.Company ID="1" /><Microsoft.Dynamics.Hrm.Entity.Employee ID="001557" /></entityKey>')
,('3EF8C35D-6227-486A-B86B-00BD5991E188','<entityKey><Microsoft.Dynamics.Common.Company.Company ID="1" /><Microsoft.Dynamics.Hrm.Entity.Employee ID="001740" /></entityKey>')

select * from @table
```

My desired output would be:

```
 UserID                                CompanyID    Employeeid
----------                             ----------   ----------
D8851830-EF23-44BE-BB17-0008D70F9F5B   1            002001
78E42A10-D7CE-4B40-86F2-001549F5A3C2   1            001079
1F899A87-6186-4E2B-BA18-0076A4D95836   1            001997
CB043358-0B16-4055-A806-00A63964C1A9   1            001557
3EF8C35D-6227-486A-B86B-00BD5991E188   1            001740
```

If possible, I would like to do this without using substring. Yes it may work for this example, but other situations may arise with more complex xml and I'd like to learn how to do it right.

In the end, I will join to the table [MbfUserWindowsIdentity], which includes the AD username in the format of domain\username along with another column holding UserID.

If anyone knows of a better place to pull the EmployeeID, that would work too. Basically we just need to export the GP EmployeeID with the AD Username.

For those that are curious, we are building an employee directory using the data in GP, but the directory will have functionality to allow a user to opt out of publishing select personal information, hence the tie to AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, cast the "constituent" field as XML - in the Dynamics/GP database this field datatype is NVARCHAR. 
Then, use Xquery to extract the value from the XML field. See example below:

```
SELECT UserID 
,CAST(t.Constituent AS XML).value('(/entityKey/Microsoft.Dynamics.Common.Company.Company/@ID)[1]','int') as CompanyID
,CAST(t.Constituent AS XML).value('(/entityKey/Microsoft.Dynamics.Hrm.Entity.Employee/@ID)[1]','varchar(10)') as EmployeeID
FROM @table as t
```

To answer the other part of your question, this is the only place I have found where it stores the EmployeeId along with the userid in the same table.

I hope this helps!